# JQuery function, wrapping and live binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, bind, live

I've written a nice function to wrap an input with increment/decrement buttons:

```
$.fn.qDecInc = function(){
return this.wrap('<span id="qButtons" />').after($('<span/>', { class: 'qIncButton' }).bind('click', function() {
    var ov = 0;
    if (isNaN($(this).val())){
        ov = 0;
    } else {
        ov = $(this).val();
    }
    if (ov < 99){
        var nv = parseFloat(ov) + 1;
        $(this).val(nv);
        $(this).keyup();
        $(this).change();
    }
}), $('<span/>', { class: 'qDecButton', style: 'top: 11px;' }).bind('click', function() {
    var ov = 0;
    if (isNaN($(this).val())){
        ov = 0;
    } else {
        ov = $(this).val();
    }
    if (ov > 0){
        var nv = parseFloat(ov) - 1;
        $(this).val(nv);
        $(this).keyup();
        $(this).change();
    }
}));
}
```

Values get updated, but the inputs not.
I've tried

```
$(this).live("change");
```

and even

```
$("body").delegate($(this), "change");
```

to no avail.
What did I miss?

http://jsfiddle.net/MVxsA/1/ - here's a jsfiddle for your convenience.

Comment: After your code samples when you mention the other techniques you've tried, do you mean inside the handler? As far as I can tell, the first problem to solve is that the click isn't being bound. http://jsfiddle.net/MVxsA/3/ - in addition to the old-school alert() debugging not popping, I don't actually see the values get updated either.

Comment: Thank you. I've actually used .bind() to bind the events, but lost my mind for a second and changed it back to .live() before posting :). As seen in the fiddle, .bind() does actually work (and changes the $(this).val() values), but the following change and and keyup events wouldn't get called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two issues

1. in this context, you should use `.bind('click', function() {...})` instead of `live()`.  Or you can use the convenient shortcut method `.click(function() {...})`.  The function `live()` is used when elements will be added to the dom later, and you want jQuery to automatically attach listeners to the new elements at that time.  For this reason, `live()` also requires a selector (which your example omits).
2. When inside an event handler, `this` refers to the element on which the listener was fired.  So in this case, `this` is the qIncButton or qDecButton, *not* the element to which the plugin is applied.

Here's how these issues can be corrected:

```
$.fn.qDecInc = function(){
    var self = this;
    return self.wrap('<span id="qButtons" />').after($('<span/>', { class: 'qIncButton' }).click(function() {
        console.log("up");
        var ov = 0;
        if (isNaN($(self).val())){
            ov = 0;
        } else {
            ov = $(self).val();
        }
        if (ov < 99){
            var nv = parseFloat(ov) + 1;
            $(self).val(nv);
            $(self).keyup();
            $('body').change();
        }
    }), $('<span/>', { class: 'qDecButton', style: 'top: 11px;' }).click(function() {
        console.log("down");
        var ov = 0;
        if (isNaN($(self).val())){
            ov = 0;
        } else {
            ov = $(self).val();
        }
        if (ov > 0){
            var nv = parseFloat(ov) - 1;
            $(self).val(nv);
            $(self).keyup();
            $(self).change();
        }
    }));
}
```

[Your updated jsFiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/coltrane/MVxsA/2/)

Comment: Thank you, the $(this) thingie was totally missed by me. :)